# How do I have an UL of H1 without vertical space between the LI's?

Tags: css

I"m trying to create a bullet list of h2 items.

```html
    <ul>
   <li><h2 style="line-height:28px;font-size:35px">  Some text here</h2></li>
   <li><h2>  Some more text here and this happens to be very long sometimes so it wraps like this.</h2></li>
</ul>
```

But if I reduce the line height enough to avoid a big space between bullets then the wrapped bullet line has too little space.

It seems that there is extra vertical space (maybe an extra CR?) after an h2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, browsers add padding and/or margins to all heading tags. If you remove that margin you should be good to go

```css
h2{margin:0;padding:0}
```

```html
<ul>
   <li><h2 style="line-height:28px;font-size:35px">  Some text here</h2></li>
   <li><h2>  Some more text here and this happens to be very long sometimes so it wraps like this.</h2></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put this in the `<head>` section of your html, or add this `h2` style to your separate cascading style sheet file if you have one:

`<style> h2 { margin: 0; padding: 0; } </style>`

Comment: Excellent solution. I gave you an upvote but gave the answer to someone who also provided a brief explanation and code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the `<h2>` element has a default display setting of `block`.  This automatically makes it take up the whole line, pushing everything beneath it.  Kind of like adding the `<br/>` element after something.  Change it to `display: inline;` to fix the problem.

*NOTE: You then won't need the `line-height` property.*

```html
<ul>
   <li><h2 style="font-size:35px;display:inline;">  Some text here</h2></li>
   <li><h2>  Some more text here and this happens to be very long sometimes so it wraps like this.</h2></li>
</ul>
```

You may also need to change the `margin` and `padding` properties, if this doesn't take away enough space.  `<h2>` elements have some predefined settings on those properties as well.

```html
<ul>
   <li><h2 style="font-size:35px;display:inline;padding:0;margin:0;">  Some text here</h2></li>
   <li><h2>  Some more text here and this happens to be very long sometimes so it wraps like this.</h2></li>
</ul>
```